# Postgres permission denied

Tags: postgresql

I'm a rookie with postgres, and after I started the postgresql-11.service,
I enter in 'su postgres', and try create my db, but appear this message:

```
[root@127 nemo]# systemctl enable postgresql-11.service
[root@127 nemo]# systemctl start postgresql-11.service
[root@127 nemo]# su postgres
bash-4.4$ createdb mydb
could not change directory to "/home/nemo": Permission denied
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "postgres", database "template1", SSL off"
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createdb` needs to connect to a database to issue a `CREATE DATABASE` SQL statement, and by default it will use:

- a Unix socket domain connection
- the current username from the shell as the database user (so `postgres` in your case)
- `template1` as the database

When it does that, in your case you get this error message:

> createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  no
>   pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "postgres", database
>   "template1", SSL off"

It indicates that `postgres` as a database user does not have the permission to connect through a Unix domain socket (that's what `[local]` means).

This is **unusual**, since in general, postgres installers on Unix tend to install a `pg_hba.conf` starting with this rule:

```
local   all       postgres       peer
```

Meaning that the `postgres` Unix user has the right to connect locally to any database as the `postgres` database user, which suits the needs of administrating databases, including creating new ones.

In fact your `pg_hba.conf` does not look like a default one. The simplest way to proceed to immediately solve the problem of database creation would be to edit it,  add the above line as the first rule, and reload the postgres service.

Answer (score 0):

`su postgres` leaves you in a weird state where your are currently in a directory which you have no access to be in.

You probably want to do `su - postgres`, which will leave you in postgres's home directory.